# Is it possible to use infix notation ~ for functions with one argument or more than 2 arguments?

Tags: syntax

According to a Mathematica textbook, we can write `N[x,n]` by using infix notation as `x ~ N ~ n`. How about other functions with one argument or more than 2 arguments, is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One can use `Sequence` for such purposes

```
Sequence[]~f~x
x~f~Sequence[]
```

> f[x]
>
> f[x]

```
x1~f~Sequence[x2, x3]
```

> f[x1, x2, x3]

Answer (score 3):

If, in an input cell, you type the expression,

```
x1 ~ f ~ x2 ~ f ~ x3
```

it will evaluate to

```
f[f[x1,x2],x3]
```

UNLESS the symbol f has the attribute **Flat** in which case it will evaluate to

```
f[x1,x2,x3]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Infix[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Infix%5b%5d.html) documentation page, you can:

```
x1 ~ f ~ x2 ~ f ~ x3 ~ ... === Infix[f[x1,x2,x3,...]]
```

Comment: How about functions with one argument?

Comment: Did you actually try what you wrote above? This is wrong. Infix _notation_ is primarily for 2 argument functions and works for multiple arguments when the function is `Flat`. The `Infix` _function_ that you refer to is only a typesetting function.

Comment: @StiffJokes I'd use [`@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/@.html). edit: @rm -rf: Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: @shrx It's confusing, especially since `F1` on `~` takes you there... the `Infix` _function_ is more for typesetting than the function calls notation. For instance, `Prefix[f[x]]` will give you `f@x`, but this `f@x` is not equivalent to typing out `f@x` (try evaluating the two). Check out the full forms: `Infix[f[x1, x2, x3]] // FullForm` and `x1~f~x2~f~x3 // FullForm`

Comment: @rm-rf Oh! I miss the times when those were hot themes here .)