# How to Write Partition with Infix?

Tags: syntax

The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html) says that using `Infix` ~, the following input

```
f[e1,e2,e3,...]
```

can be rewritten as

```
e1~f~e2~f~e3~...
```

So, for the sake of example, consider the following list defined below.

```
samplelist = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

If I wanted to Partition this list into subsets of 3 with an offset of 2, I would do so by entering

```
Partition[samplelist, 3, 2]
```

which would output

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

Logic then follows that if I wanted to achieve the same result using `Infix`, I should input

```
samplelist~Partition~3~Partition~2
```

But, this instead returns

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I use `Infix` correctly to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The documentation is slightly misleading, but it doesn't actually say that `f[a,b,c]` can be given as `a~f~b~f~c`, if you read carefully.  It says that `Infix` will print it in that form.  `a~f~b~f~c` is in fact `f[f[a, b], c]`.  Only use `~infix~` notation for functions that take two arguments.  IMO it's quite confusing to use such a notation when the function is not associative anyway ...

Comment: Ah, that's what I started to suspect. After playing around with it, I thought that stringing multiple infixes along made it like a pseudo nested function. Thanks for clarifying the info :)

Comment: Related: [(6955)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6955/121), [(23818)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23818/121), [(39538)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39538/121)

Comment: @Szabolcs How is it any more confusing for a non-associative function than e.g. `x // f // g // h` is?  Either form requires one to know in which direction a particular operator must be read.  Or do you prefer explicit bracketing in all such cases?

Answer (score 9):

The documentation you linked to is more about how [`Infix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infix.html) is used to define output formats. You can find more information on how to use functions in infix form in the tutorials [Special Ways to Input Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html) and [Operator Input Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html).
If you really want to use `Partition` in the infix form with an offset, you can use

```
samplelist ~Partition~ Sequence[3, 2]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9}}`

Answer (score 7):

As commented by Szabolcs ~infix~ syntax works only with two arguments.  Karsten's clever use of `Sequence` does not change this fact.

As a leading proponent of ~infix~ syntax around here I believe that that binary nature is one of two primary benefits this notation has, the other being reduction of stacked [[[ brackets ]]].  One can at a glance tell from `~function~` that `function` is being used with two arguments; this imparts information that it not present in `function[` where one must keep scanning to determine the number of arguments.  Similarly `function @` and `// function` can be seen at a glance to have one argument.