# Learning Shortcut Syntax - Newbie Question

Tags: syntax

I'm learning Mathematica in order to work with Linear Algebra.  I found a good post here about matrix manipulation, but realized that the author used conventions that I couldn't find documented in the Wolfram explanations.  Can someone point me to where these are explained.

[Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/elegant-operations-on-matrix-rows-and-columns)

Specific questions:

**Range@12** - I see that it's the same as Range[12].  Where is the use of @ defined?

**~Partition~ 3** - Again I think I see the use of the tilde, but couldn't find where its use is defined.  The documentation seems to say its an "infix" without definition.

**//** And yet again I think I see what it means, but want to understand specifically.  Where is it explained?

Comment: Look up `Postfix`, `Prefix` and `Infix` in the documentation. When I search for `@`, `//` and `~` respectively these do show up in the documentation.

Comment: For the meaning and references of these symbols and many others, check this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/31159).

Comment: This is all described in the Operator Precedence table, along with the highly pertinent binding power information.  I am therefore marking this as *already has an answer* redirecting to a Q&A that discusses this.  See also the general reference answer linked by Xavier above, and if you please my own terse opinion on the use of these notations in [(87124)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87124/121)

Answer (score -1):

Try on google or any search tool to type

special ways to imput  expression wolfram mathematica

or in help

postfix operator

you will find the answer needed

Comment: -1. The meaning of shortcuts are notoriously hard to find through search engines.(But can sometimes be found by searching in the documentation.)

Comment: V. E.  for you the answer  which is in SpecialWaysToInputExpressions accessible by the help  is so hard to understand. On many cases I have asked questions which have a simple answer in the documentation. Sometimes we are shy to look at it.

Comment: And to finish look V. E. look at the last words of the question : Where is it explained? I was not thinking my answer merits a down vote

Comment: If you had linked the page, it would have been a good answer! But I don't think "Google it" is a good answer in this case, even if you tell him what to google..