# A possible issue in combination of the Infix operator ~ with Sequence

Tags: hold, operators, sequence

There are other similar questions on this site about [using the Infix operator for more than two arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39538/37848), which I have read. But there is one thing that I wasn't able to understand and couldn't figure out why. Consider this line:

```
#~If~Sequence[2, 3] & /@ {False, True, False}
```

which gives the output `{3, 2, 3}` as expected. Now if I understand correctly, `Sequence @@ {2, 3}` is the same as `Sequence[2, 3]`, but if you put this in the above line:

```
#~If~(Sequence @@ {2, 3}) & /@ {False, True, False}
```

it results in `{Null, 2, 3, Null}`. Why does this happen?

Is there some kind of workaround to make it work?
I tried playing around with `Hold` and its variations without any luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at:

```
Attributes[If]
(* {HoldRest, Protected} *)
```

Now consider:

```
If[#1, Sequence @@ {2, 3}] &
```

Because of the "HoldRest", the Sequence will not be evaluated as you can see by e.g.:

```
If[#1, Sequence @@ {2, 3}] &[True]
(* Sequence[2, 3] *)
```

And the following returns Null:

```
If[#1, Sequence @@ {2, 3}] &[False]
```

Comment: Thanks. Therefore `#~If~Evaluate[Sequence @@ {2, 3}] & /@ {False, True, False}` gives the desired result